# Raspberry pie static audio IO issue

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi3, soundcard, pyttsx

I am a newbie in raspberry and linux.
I have set the external USB sound card as the primary sound card of the raspberry pi 3 but I am unable to get a voice output.
For the output, earphone with mic is being used. The code is not showing any error but its not giving any output and the code is given below:

```
import sys
import pyttsx

# main() function
def main():
  # use sys.argv if needed
  print 'running speech-test.py...'
  engine = pyttsx.init()
  str = "I speak. Therefore. I am.  "
  if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    str = sys.argv[1]
  engine.say(str)
  engine.runAndWait()

# call main
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```